# jquery trigger not opening link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a id="divLink" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>   
<a id="divLinkOpen" href="#" >Open</a>

$('#divLinkOpen').unbind('click').click(function() {     
    $('#divLinkOpen').trigger("click");
});
```

trigger not opening the link for google

Answer (score 4):

You cannot open a link by triggering the event, you can change the `href` property of the `location` object or use `open` method of the `window` object.

```
$('#divLinkOpen').click(function() {     
    location.href = $('#divLink')[0].href;
    // window.open($('#divLink')[0].href)
});
```

Note that you are triggering the event for the clicked element, this way your click handler executed recursively.

Comment: Or use window.open to open the href in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

```
$('#divLinkOpen').trigger("click");
```

The above link triggers a click on divLinkOpen and not on divLink. Even if you were to change this to

```
$('#divLink').trigger("click");
```

It would still not work as divLink element does not have a click event handler.

I would go with undefined's answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
<a id="divLink" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>   
<a id="divLinkOpen" href="#">Open</a>


    $('#divLinkOpen').click(function() {     
        $('#divLinkOpen').unbind('click');
        window.open($('#divLink').attr('href'));
    });
```